# Не могу запустить сервер повторно ejabberd

Tags: linux

Подскажите, вчера запустил сервер, работали клиенты, админка.
Со вчера ничего не менял, комп перезагрузил видимо и команда из под root:

```
/etc/init.d/ejabberd restart
```

Теперь пишет это:

```
Stopping ejabberd...
Failed RPC connection to the node ejabberd@localhost: nodedown
```

как можно запустить сервер повторно?

Comment: Просто `/etc/init.d/ejabberd start` ?

Answer (score 0):

окей, сервер запустить удалось, выполнил так:

1. зашел под root sudo -i
2. cd /opt/ejabberd-21.01/bin
3. ./ejabberdctl start
4. /etc/init.d/ejabberd start

кажется ejabberdctl падает при выкл компа.